# Code no longer in separate file

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

Ok so I made a new website project in Visual Studio 2015 RC after closing and reopening VS and the project I noticed all my pages now have another page beside them, pageName.aspx.designer.cs
But the real problem is it seems VS no longer considers the separate code files of each page and when I auto generate a button_click function for example it generates it in a  element inside the aspx page and not inside the pageName.aspx.cs
What do I do?

> ERROR: Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line
>   Error     'ASP.pages_deleteaccount_aspx' does not contain a definition
>   for 'SubmitButton_Click' and no extension method 'SubmitButton_Click'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.pages_deleteaccount_aspx'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)       G:\2015\FaceBook\FaceBook\Pages\DeleteAccount.aspx  45

Comment: seems like you had created a WebApplication and trying to open it as Website.

Comment: How shall I open it correctly then? using the .sln file doesn't work either

Comment: You can open it via project file .csproj or else you can create a new empty webapplication project delete unwanted files from it and add existing projects files into it, while doing this keep in mind to cross check namespaces.

Comment: Great thanks, that worked (opening through csproj)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you had created a WebApplication and trying to open it as Website.

To solve it you can open it via project file .csproj or else you can create a new empty webapplication project delete unwanted files from it and add existing projects files into it, while doing this keep in mind to cross check namespaces.